# Normal vector from 2 3d points

Tags: vector, 3d, points, normals, plane

Is it possible to define the normal of an oriented plane from 2 3D points-p1,p2?
If so, is it n=cross(p2,p1)~matlab~.Or can it be n=p2-p1?? I found the second way and i want to know if just the deduction is the normal of a plane(unknown plane).

For example i have the p1,p2 points.I want to find the normal from p2->p1 for a plane fixed at p2.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the normal from p2->p1 for a plane fixed at p2". What is the point p1 supposed to be? What determines which way the plane faces?

Comment: well to be specific points are trajectories of joints of a skeleton(motion tracking).So i have a plane Π fixed at the joint p2=lhip,normal defined from p1=rhip,lhip(rhip->lhip) and i want to test if rankle is closer to Π than lankle      .So ,"The normal n is the direction vector from the point halfway between the hips to the root." that the meaning of the question.thank you in advance for any   response

Comment: So p2->p1 is the normal and you want it as a vector? Then it's p1-p2. This has nothing special to do with normals, it's the basic way to get a vector between 2 points.

Comment: So if i have p1-p2 it's ok to assume it as normal of a plane, and if i have a point p3 in the plane then that it will be dot(p3,n)=0? Thank you interjay for your answer i just wanted to confirm it!!

Comment: No, it will be dot(p3-p2, n)=0 if p3 and p2 are points on the plane.